# How to use map/reduce to fit one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of servers and an array of jobs.

```
var servers = [
  {
    name: "Lan",
    capacity: 5
  }, 

  {
    name: "Stark",
    capacity: 3
  },

  {
    name: "Tar",
    capacity: 3
  }
];

var jobs = [
  {
    name: "Tye",
    capacity: 2
  }, 

  {
    name: "Arya",
    capacity: 3
  },

  {
    name: "Rob",
    capacity: 3
  }
];
```

I want to be able to run all jobs using the least number of servers (a job can only run on one server, it cannot run across 2 different servers). A server can run any number of jobs upto its capacity. So in the case above server "Lan" with capacity 5 can run jobs "Tye" and "Arya" with capacities (2 + 3).
Is it possible to use map / reduce to solve this. The result should be:

```
result  = [
  {
    name: "Lan",
    capacity: 5,
    jobs: ["Tye", "Arya"]
  },

  {
    name: "Stark",
    capacity: 3,
    jobs: ["Rob"]
  }, 

  {
    name: "Tar",
    capacity: 3,
    jobs: []
  }

]
```

Comment: It's probably possible, but have you tried anything? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I think no. Since this is a Multiple Knapsack Problem.